# Yii2: Codeception functional testing with subdomains

Tags: testing, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, functional-testing, codeception

How do we configure Codeception to test frontend and backend applications, which are accessible through their own subdomains:

- Frontend: `project1.example.com`
- Backend: `backend1.example.com`

The default codeception configuration in [yii2-app-advanced](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced) expects both *frontend* and *backend* to be on the same domain (`localhost`)!

Comment: What test do you want to run? Application url you can set in yml files: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/frontend/tests/acceptance.suite.yml.example

Comment: @TomaszKane as the title says: functional tests. Your link is for acceptance tests.

Comment: OK, this probably helps: http://codeception.com/docs/modules/Yii2 ?

Comment: @TomaszKane It does not help. Setting `entryUrl` and `entryScript` has no effect, codeception still runs functional tests on `http://localhost` no matter what you put in there.

Comment: can you paste you test and yml files to question? How you run your tests? I have project with two applications (foo.dev, api.foo.dev), no define any urls in my code/config and functional test just works.